# Used dd to copy and half of my new disks storage capacity is unavailable

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I used `dd` to copy a 2TB disk to a 4TB disk (dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc status=progress) but now my 4TB disk is reporting only 2TB of available space. Is there any way I can get the other 2TB back without making a new copy.

If I make a new copy should I used 'dd' in some other way or resort to 'cp'

There is nothing wrong with the 2TB disk, it's just a bit old and I need more space. Both disk are WD Red NAS disks.

Comment: what type of filesystem is it and what os\Distro? basically you copied the entire disk, including the partition table and the volume filesystem, so it makes perfect sense that the resulting partition is of the same size as the original.

Comment: Both disks were formatted as EXT4 on Ubuntu 20.04 Server edition. I understand what you say, Frank, but is there anything I can do to fix it

Answer (score 3):

Your *filesystem* is reporting 2TB of available space, not the disk.

Your old disk had a 2TB partition defined, so after copying the entire thing (including the list of partitions!), the new disk also has a 2TB partition defined<sup>1</sup>. If you take a look using `gparted` or `gnome-disks`, you'll probably see a 4TB disk with half of it in use by the data partition and the other half 'unallocated'.

Use GParted or some other partitioning tool to expand the partition to the entire disk.

(Once the partition is resized, the ext4 filesystem also needs to be grown to fill the new capacity, but GParted will do that automatically. With some other tools you may need to run `resize2fs` manually.)

---

<sup>1</sup> (Note that as far as the disk knows, partitions are just *data* – they're only recognized by the OS, not by the disk itself, and having smaller partitions cannot cause the physical disk to report a different capacity.

Partition definitions i.e. start–end ranges are stored in sectors 0–33 of /dev/sdb, and any tool that copies the raw contents of /dev/sdb will end up transferring the partition table too.)

Comment: Thanks user1686 and Frank,

Comment: user1686, expanding the partition most likely won't work. A detailed explanation  why will follow tomorrow hopefully - being still sick in bed an not sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

> If I make a new copy should I used 'dd' in some other way or resort to 'cp'

When you duplicated your drive entirely you copied your partition table as well.
There are two types of partition tables, the old MBR and the new GPT.
In combination with a sector size of 512 byte (shown at the drive interface) the old MBR scheme only allows for a partition size of 2TB.

There is some hack under linux I forgot to use a 4 TB drive with 2 TB + 2 TB partitions.

But the smart way to avoid individual copies using the cp command would have been as follows:

1. Partition the duplicate destination 4 TB drive using the GPT scheme and create one partition with the size of your one and only source partition (2 TB). Formating that 2 TB partition is not necessary.
2. Copy the source partition to the target partition:

**dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sdc1**

3. In case of having another partition left to copy, add another partition with the size of the related source partition and go back to stop 2 and increment the partition number

(**dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sdc2**

**dd if=/dev/sdb2 of=/dev/sdc3**

**dd if=/dev/sdb3 of=/dev/sdc4**

...)

Copying this way you avoid having two drives with the same UUID.
Furthermore you installed a partition table scheme that supports all currently available disc sizes beyond 2 TB and you will be able to create further partitions on the target drive or - if your software supports it - extend the 2TB target partition.

Modern linux operating systems and all current Windows systems support GPT.

> Both disks were formatted as EXT4 on Ubuntu 20.04 Server edition. I understand what you say, Frank, but is there anything I can do to fix it

Assuming that there are some sectors left between your partition table and your first partition you could convert your target disk from using a MBR scheme to GPT quickly (maybe using Gparted?). The GPT scheme needs some additionals sectors at the beginning of the drive. If those sectors are missing converting the disk would involve moving the target partition somes sectors towards the end of the disk. That would consume as much time as redoing the copy job properly as described above.