# Cloning a 2 TB disk with dos label to a 4 TB one with gpt label

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, fdisk

Hello everybody out there using Linux,

Cloning disk using `dd` usually works fine for me, but I ran into troubles when cloning a 2 TB disk to a 4 TB one: the `dos` label would need to be changed to a `gpt` one to support enlarging to the new size. Is it possible to change that after having cloned the disk with `dd`?

Comment: what do you mean with dos label? Do you by any chance refer to mbr?

Comment: If you're asking before cloning then creating (GPT) partitions first (of equal or larger sizes) and cloning partition by partition is probably a good idea (the filesystems will need to be expanded separately). If you're asking after the cloning then please [edit] and post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdX`, where `sdX` is the 4 TB disk. Which case is it?

Comment: @LPChip `fdisk` reports `Disklabel type: dos` for DOS partition table in MBR, `Disklabel type: gpt` for GPT. I interpret the question according to these.

Comment: There is a similar question here that I answered: https://superuser.com/questions/1688340/used-dd-to-copy-and-half-of-my-new-disks-storage-capacity-is-unavailable/1688555#1688555

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after cloning the disk, you can use `gdisk` to perform in-place conversion of the DOS/MBR label to a GPT one. (There is no specific menu command for that – the label will be automatically converted to GPT as soon as you use `w` to write it.)

(For scripts, the same thing can be done non-interactively using `sgdisk --mbrtogpt`.)

---

Alternatively, first create a GPT label on the new disk, create all partitions of the exact sizes needed (using fdisk, sfdisk, gdisk, or whatever tool you prefer), and clone the individual partitions using `dd` one by one.

This method has advantages – e.g. when cloning a partition with NTFS filesystem, you can instead use `ntfsclone` which skips empty areas making the process faster.

One possible way to clone the partition *layout* from a MBR disk to a GPT disk is:

```
sfdisk --dump /dev/OLD | sed "s/^label:.*/label: gpt/; /^label-id:/d" | sfdisk /dev/NEW
```

(Don't bother cloning the BIOS boot sector manually, as most likely you'll need to install a new GPT-aware boot sector anyway.)

Comment: The command `sudo sgdisk --mbrtogpt /dev/sdb` ran without an error message, but I can't boot the disk.

Comment: Yeah, because the bootloader that's currently on the disk is expecting the original MBR layout. At minimum, if you want to convert BIOS-MBR to BIOS-GPT, you'll have to reinstall GRUB to that disk. _regardless_ of the conversion method that was used. (If you also want to convert it from BIOS-style to UEFI, or if you _need_ to convert BIOS to UEFI because it contains Windows, that's a whole another topic -- and one that already has several threads posted about.)